# How to add the ID in jquery without using Short Hand Operator

Tags: jquery

How to add the ID in jquery without ShortHand Operator

> I want to close Bootstrap alert boxes, so I use this line

```
var newAlertIds=0;
$("#"+ newAlertIds).alert('close');
```

> But sometimes I need to close the alert box whose value is greater by one digit. Like this

```
$("#"+ newAlertIds+1).alert('close');
```

> But the **above line is not working**. Any suggestions?
>
> Remember I **dont want to use Short Hand Operators** like this

```
 $("#"+ newAlertIds++).alert('close');
```

Comment: Open your browser console and type `"#"+ 0 + 1` and see what the result is.

Comment: Then type `"#"+ (0 + 1)` and see what the result is.

Comment: first plus join string but second plus work like first. If you wrap value into (0+1) it will be plus like number like @Taplar said.

Comment: @Taplar When I m writing "#" + 0 + 1 , its working

Comment: `"#" + (0+1)` is also working

Comment: `"#"+ 0 + 1` in the console results in `#01`

Comment: Finally `$("#"+ (newAlertIds+1)).alert('close');` is working.
Thank you bro @Taplar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you describe is related on how the interpreter executes the expressions (the implicit order of evaluation). In your case:

`"#" + newAlertIds + 1`

will be evaluated to

`("#" + newAlertIds) + 1`

So, assuming that `newAlertIds` is an integer, `("#" + newAlertIds)` executes first and generates a `string`, then `1` will be concatenated to that string. For example, if `newAlertIds` is equal to `24`, you will get the result of `#241`.

```js
let newAlertIds = 24;
console.log("#" + newAlertIds + 1);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

To solve it, you will need to force (some way) the implicit order for evaluating your expression, like `"#" + (newAlertIds + 1)`. This will output `#25` in relation to previous example.

```js
let newAlertIds = 24;
console.log("#" + (newAlertIds + 1));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```